# What is the coefficient of $\sqrt{2}$ in $f(\sqrt{2})$ where $f(x) = 3 - x + 2x^2 - 5x^3 +4x^4?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> What is the coefficient of $\sqrt2$ in $f(\sqrt2)$ where $f(x) = 3 - x + 2x^2 - 5x^3 +4x^4?$

Hi
I'm studying polynomial rings.
I don't get what the question is asking me to do.
Should I just plug in $\sqrt2 $ in $f(x)$?
Isn't the definition of coefficient the number in front of a variable? How can there be a coefficient of a number, i.e. $\sqrt2$?

Am I missing something..

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you compute $f(\sqrt{2})$ you'll obtain a result of the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$, where $a,b$ are integers. You are just being asked to say what $b$ is.

Comment: ah!!Thank you.. geez

Answer (score 0):

The square root doesn't survive even powers.  As $-x-5x^3=-x(1+5x^2)$ the coefficient is $-(1+5\cdot2)$.

Comment: i.e. if we [split](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/768183/242) $\,f\,$ into even and odd parts $\,f(x)  = f(x^2) +  x\,h(x^2)\,$ then $\,f(\sqrt 5) = f(5) + h(5)\sqrt 5\ \ $